# Getting TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting this error for my below code when I start my server. What is wrong in this code?

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
```

shop.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express');

const rootDir = require('../util/path');
const adminData = require('./admin');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const products = adminData.products;
    res.render('shop', {
        prods: products,
        docTitle: 'Shop'
    });
});
```

admin.js

```
module.exports = router;

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const rootDir = require('../util/path');

const router = express.Router();

const products = [];

// /admin/add-product => GET
router.get('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(rootDir, 'views', 'add-product.html'));
});

// /admin/add-product => POST
router.post('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
    products.push({
        title: req.body.title
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
module.exports = products;
```

app.js:

```
 const path = require('path');
 const express = require('express');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 const app = express();

 app.set('view engine', 'pug');
 app.set('views', 'views');

 const adminData = require('./routes/admin');
 const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: false
 }));

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

 app.use('/admin', adminData.routes);
 app.use(shopRoutes);

 app.use((req, res, next) => {
     res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', '404.html'));
 });

 app.listen(3000, () => {
     console.log('Server started!!');
 });
```

Comment: Perhaps it is because you forgot to export router from shop.js.

`module.exports = router` in shop.js

Comment: @MohitYadav: Thanks for pointing out but if you see my admin.js first line is `module.exports = router;` that is from shop.js

Comment: ok then try `app.use('/', shopRoutes)`

Comment: @MohitYadav: I modified my code as per your suggestion in app.js file but that did not solve my problem. In app.js  `app.use('/admin', adminData.routes);` this code is breaking.

Comment: @RohanDongre you can rollback the change for above comment as it does not make a difference, the issue is with multiple module.exports as you overwrote default export above, just use 

`exports.products = products;
module.exports = router;`

in admin.js, this should work.

Comment: @MohitYadav: I tried this also but no luck.

Comment: can you perhaps share some node runtime env for this? it will be helpful in that way.

Comment: @MohitYadav what do mean by runtime environment? OS, node version?

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox env with your code?

Comment: I don't know how to create codesandbox env. Can you please guide me?

Comment: Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-davinci-sjzzg)

As suggested by @stanley `module.exports = { router, products };` in admin.js and `app.use("/admin", adminData.router);` in app.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365290/typeerror-router-use-requires-a-middleware-function-but-got-a-undefined)

Comment: For the search phrase "TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined", there are 27 search results on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your exported object is being overwritten here

```
module.exports = router;
module.exports = products;
```

Essentially, you are exporting only `products` object.
Try

```
module.exports = { router, products };
```

and

```
app.use('/admin', adminData.router);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're following correctly? Can I have a look at your updated source code? @RohanDongre

Comment: admin.js
`module.exports = {
    router,
    products
};`

app.js
`const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminData = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// app.use('/admin', adminData);
app.use(adminData);
app.use(shopRoutes.router);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started!!');
});`

Comment: `module.exports = {router, products}` is meant for `shop.js`

Comment: I updated my shop.js with `module.exports = {router, products}` and now I am getting `products
    ^

ReferenceError: products is not defined`

Comment: Oh shoot I mixed up your file name, it was really meant for `admin.js` and in `app.js` it should be like `app.use(adminData.router)` and `app.use(shopRoutes)`

Comment: That really worked but now I am getting 404 page not found. It is not redirecting to /admin/add-product page.

Comment: `app.use('/admin', adminData.router)`

Comment: I added that but still 404

Comment: Not adding, replacing `app.use(adminData.router)` with it. Another note, it should be placed before `app.use(shopRoutes)`

Comment: I have this code `app.use('admin', adminData.router);
app.use(shopRoutes);`but still 404.

Comment: Sorry it worked.. I was missing / in `app.use('admin', adminData.router);`